# I was creating a collage method that had the use of static, I was wondering how I could invoke this method without calling out Picture p1/p2/p3?

Tags: java

I want to know how to invoke createCollage without calling p1, p2, and p3, due to static.

```
//This is my current use in my AdvanceCollage class:  
Picture combine = new Picture(3*pictObj.getWidth(), pictObj.getHeight());        
combine.createCollage(p1,p2,p3); //goal is to use the method without p1,p2,p3       
combine.explore();
```

---

```
public static void createCollage(Picture p1, Picture p2, Picture p3)
    {
        Pixel sPixel = null, tPixel = null, sPixel2 = null, tPixel2 = null, sPixel3 = null, 
        tPixel3 = null;
        int targetX = 0, targetX2 = 0, targetX3 = 0, targetY = 0, targetY2 = 0, targetY3 = 0;

        // Add the first picture
        for (int sourceX = 0; sourceX < p1.getWidth(); sourceX++)
        {
            for (int sourceY = 0; sourceY < p1.getHeight(); sourceY++)
            {
                // code to copy the pixels go here
                sPixel = p1.getPixel(sourceX,sourceY);
                tPixel = p1.getPixel(targetX,targetY);
                tPixel.setColor(sPixel.getColor());
                // target pixel is (sourceX, sourceY)
            }
        }
        // Add the second picture
        for (int sourceX2 = 0; sourceX2 < p2.getWidth(); sourceX2++)
        {
            for (int sourceY2 = 0; sourceY2 < p2.getHeight(); sourceY2++)
            {
                // code to copy the pixels go here
                sPixel2 = p2.getPixel(sourceX2,sourceY2);
                tPixel2 = p2.getPixel(targetX2,targetY2);
                tPixel2.setColor(sPixel2.getColor());
                // target pixel is (sourceX + pic1.getWidth(), sourceY)
            }
        }
        // Add the third picture
        for (int sourceX3 = 0; sourceX3 < p1.getWidth(); sourceX3++)
        {
            for (int sourceY3 = 0; sourceY3 < p1.getHeight(); sourceY3++)
            {
                // code to copy the pixels go here
                sPixel3 = p3.getPixel(sourceX3,sourceY3);
                tPixel3 = p3.getPixel(targetX3,targetY3);
                tPixel3.setColor(sPixel3.getColor());
                // target pixel is (sourceX + pic1.getWidth() + pic2.getWidth(), sourceY)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "goal is to use the method without p1,p2,p3" but you need to pass in three `Picture`s. That's just how the method is defined.

Comment: So you want to call a method that does something with 3 pictures without providing 3 pictures? Where should the information about the pictures come from in this case? Also "due to static" is not really telling us what the problem is.

Comment: Also: Java is to JavaScript as Ham is to Hamster: don't tag this as JavaScript, when it's clearly Java code.

Comment: Given `createCollage` is static, you should call it as `Picture.createCollage`, and not call it on an instance as that suggests to the reader it's an instance method, which may be confusing. The fact Java allows you to call `combine.createCollage` when the method is static is - IMO - a historic mistake. That said, it is unclear to me what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If I don't get you wrong, you want a method that can pass an array or single arguments.

If this is what you want, you can use varargs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

```
createCollage(Picture... pic)
```

And then you can use it:

```
createCollage(pic1)
createCollage(pic1,pic2)
createCollage(pic1,pic2,pic3)
```

You can use static public or private also.